# Python Dictionary Additions

Tags: python

I'm a little new to Python and have been able to build a pretty nice application over here, but I've been spinning my wheels for a few hours here and I wanted to ask for a little help. Here's my loop where I'm adding to a dictionary:

```
for toast in checkin_toasts:
    if toast['checkin_id'] not in toasts:
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = {
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        }
    else:
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = toasts[toast['checkin_id']],{
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        }
```

In my case, I currently have a total of three toasts for two different checkins. The above loop gives me this dictionary:

```
{8: ({'user_id': 1, 'username': 'shaunwo'}, {'user_id': 2, 'username': 'shaunwo2'}), 9: {'user_id': 1, 'username': 'shaunwo'}}
```

And then when I try to use it in my jinja form, it works as I would expect for checkin 8 with the two toasts, but it does not work for my checkin 9 that only has one toast. I found that if I manually tweak that dictionary a bit to this:

```
{8: ({'user_id': 1, 'username': 'shaunwo'}, {'user_id': 2, 'username': 'shaunwo2'}), 9: ({'user_id': 1, 'username': 'shaunwo'},)}
```

THAT works in my jinja form beautifully. But I don't know how to revise my for loop above accordingly to give me that kind of dictionary with the (,) around the single instance for checkin 9.

Comment: I suspect your code will also work incorrectly with 3 toasts...

Comment: I think the real problem you're describing is you need to build a `dict` that maps its keys to probably any type of sequence in it (not necessarily a `tuple`), correct? Can you show a more complete example with your Jinja template and what your data looks like and how you render the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize a non-existent key of a dict with a list so that it can be consistently appended with the desired sub-dict:

```
for toast in checkin_toasts:
    toasts.setdefault(toast['checkin_id'], []).append({
        'user_id': toast['user_id'],
        'username': toast['username']
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in one branch of the `if` statement, you set `toasts[toast['checkin_id']]` to a dictionary, while in the other you set it to a tuple of its previous value and a dictionary:

```
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = {
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        }
```

vs.

```
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = (
            toasts[toast['checkin_id']],
            {
                'user_id': toast['user_id'],
                'username': toast['username']
            },
        )
```

Meanwhile, your frontend is expecting a tuple (or list) of dictionaries, regardless of whether there's 1, 2 or more.

As @blhsing posted, you can achieve this by always making it a list and appending entries to it; that's probably the neatest solution.

However, to answer the question as asked, to make a tuple of one item, there's special syntax for that in Python; a trailing comma:

```
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = {
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        },
```

If you prefer to make it more explicit, you can add parentheses:

```
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = ({
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        },)``
```

At that point, you'd also need to fix the other case to make a longer tuple rather than nesting it:

```
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = toasts[toast['checkin_id']] + ({
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        },)
```

As in @blhsing's answer, you can also combine those two into one, using the `.get()` method with a default to give you an empty tuple when adding the first toast:

```
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = toasts.get(toast['checkin_id'], ()) + ({
            'user_id': toast['user_id'],
            'username': toast['username']
        },)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are aggregating the toasts into a `tuple` if they have the same `checkin_id` and return a dictionary with `checkin_id`s as keys and toast tuples as values.

In this case, you could use `collections.defaultdict` and aggregate the toasts with the same `checkin_id` with a `tuple`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

toasts = defaultdict(tuple)
for toast in checkin_toasts:
    toasts[toast['checkin_id']] += ({
        'user_id': toast['user_id'],
        'username': toast['username']
    }, )
```

Otherwise, you could recreate the tuple every time by yourself without the help of [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).
This key point is to use the [asterisk operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) `*` to unpack the existing tuple and append the new element for the tuple assignment.

```py
for toast in checkin_toasts:
    if toast['checkin_id'] not in toasts:
        # Always create a new key with an empty tuple as its value if the key does not exist.
        toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = tuple()
    
    toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = *toasts[toast['checkin_id']], {      
        'user_id': toast['user_id'],
        'username': toast['username']
    }
    
    # # Equals to 
    # toasts[toast['checkin_id']] = tuple(*toasts[toast['checkin_id']], {      
    #    'user_id': toast['user_id'],
    #    'username': toast['username']
    # })
```

I would suggest the first approach.